# Subtituting kronecker deltas for products in simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, assumptions

I have a problem where I have some vector, $a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)^T$ that I want to have a Kronecker delta multiplication rule, $a[i]a[j] = \delta_{ij}$ (these are basically basis vectors, but for my purposes it's useful to just treat them as symbols that have that product relationship). Then I have some $n \times n$ matrices $B$ and $C$ and I want to compute $(Ba)^T(Ca)$. Note that this is just a polynomial in the components of the $a$ vector, and I'd like to simplify it according to my multiplication rule. For instance,

```
avec = {a[1], a[2], a[3]}
Bmat = {{B[1, 1], B[1, 2], B[1, 3]}, {B[2, 1], B[2, 2], 
   B[2, 3]}, {B[3, 1], B[3, 2], B[3, 3]}}
Cmat = {{C[1, 1], C[1, 2], C[1, 3]}, {C[2, 1], C[2, 2], 
   C[2, 3]}, {C[3, 1], C[3, 2], C[3, 3]}}

Transpose[(Bmat . avec)] . (Cmat . avec) // Expand
```

gives

```
a[1]^2 B[1, 1] C[1, 1] + a[1] a[2] B[1, 2] C[1, 1] + 
 a[1] a[3] B[1, 3] C[1, 1] + a[1] a[2] B[1, 1] C[1, 2] + 
 a[2]^2 B[1, 2] C[1, 2] + a[2] a[3] B[1, 3] C[1, 2] + 
 a[1] a[3] B[1, 1] C[1, 3] + a[2] a[3] B[1, 2] C[1, 3] + 
 a[3]^2 B[1, 3] C[1, 3] + a[1]^2 B[2, 1] C[2, 1] + 
 a[1] a[2] B[2, 2] C[2, 1] + a[1] a[3] B[2, 3] C[2, 1] + 
 a[1] a[2] B[2, 1] C[2, 2] + a[2]^2 B[2, 2] C[2, 2] + 
 a[2] a[3] B[2, 3] C[2, 2] + a[1] a[3] B[2, 1] C[2, 3] + 
 a[2] a[3] B[2, 2] C[2, 3] + a[3]^2 B[2, 3] C[2, 3] + 
 a[1]^2 B[3, 1] C[3, 1] + a[1] a[2] B[3, 2] C[3, 1] + 
 a[1] a[3] B[3, 3] C[3, 1] + a[1] a[2] B[3, 1] C[3, 2] + 
 a[2]^2 B[3, 2] C[3, 2] + a[2] a[3] B[3, 3] C[3, 2] + 
 a[1] a[3] B[3, 1] C[3, 3] + a[2] a[3] B[3, 2] C[3, 3] + 
 a[3]^2 B[3, 3] C[3, 3]
```

and I'd like it to just automatically set all those cross terms to 0.

I just literally don't even know where to begin. The only think I can figure out how to do is add an assumption that captures the non-crossed terms,

```
FullSimplify[Transpose[(Bmat . avec)] . (Cmat . avec) // Expand, 
 a[_]^2 == 1]
```

but that leaves all the cross terms. I've tried the only real thing I can think of,

```
FullSimplify[Transpose[(Bmat . avec)] . (Cmat . avec) // Expand, 
 a[_] a[_] == KroneckerDelta[_, _]]
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html). Also, avoid capitalizing your symbols.

```
aVec = Array[a, 3];
bMat = Array[b, {3, 3}];
cMat = Array[c, {3, 3}];

rules = {a[i_] a[j_] :> KroneckerDelta[i, j], a[_]^2 :> 1};

res = (Transpose[(bMat . aVec)] . (cMat . aVec) // Expand) /. rules
```

> `b[1, 1] c[1, 1] + b[1, 2] c[1, 2] + b[1, 3] c[1, 3] + b[2, 1] c[2, 1] + b[2, 2] c[2, 2] + b[2, 3] c[2, 3] + b[3, 1] c[3, 1] + b[3, 2] c[3, 2] + b[3, 3] c[3, 3]`

Comment: That's correct (+1), @Domen.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @Domen's answer is as follows:

```
expr = Transpose[(Bmat . avec)] . (Cmat . avec) // Expand;

rule1 = a[i_]^2 :> HoldForm[a[i]*a[i]];
rule2 = a[i_] *a[j_] :> HoldForm[KroneckerDelta[i, j]];

expr2 = expr /. rule1 /. rule2
```

[image]

Then using `ReleaseHold`:

```
Apply[ReleaseHold@*ReleaseHold, {expr2}]
```

[image]

**Remark**: This way of applying the rules allows us to observe that the replacements are made correctly.

Or equivalently:

```
expr /. {a[i_]*a[j_] :> KroneckerDelta[i, j], a[i_]*a[i_] :> KroneckerDelta[i, i]}
```

Comment: This is great and seems to work. Could you provide some insight into what's going on?

Comment: Does this really work? Am I completely confused or does it just removes all occurences of ``a`` ...

Comment: @Domen True, it is a bit confusing. Maybe it would be better to set a criterion to identify the pattern using `If` and `MatchQ`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, @Domen :-)